# how to notify update of app as red bubble on icon

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

My requirement is to set badge for notifying an app upadation. I want to know how this notification appear as badge on app icon. Any one help me please.

Comment: Did you read APNS's development documentation ?

Comment: yes,but i have doubt we get any notification for new version update from iTunes/Apple.?

Comment: AFAIK, APNS spec does not update for quite some time, and I do trust Apple will maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: So when a version of app is updated ,the icons of the app will show the badge(The apple will automatically notify).right?

Comment: No. You have to send a Push Notification to your users. Requirement: They have to subscribe to your App's Push Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the App is updated, icons of the App will NOT show the badge.

You have to send them a remote push notification to your users with badge value 1 (or any number you want), however, you may not know who's having a new version unless they launch your app and send back version information using your logic.

Requirement:

- User has to Allow your App to send Push Notification to their device, during Registration of APNS phase in your App Delegate
- User has to launch your app at least once to send back the version information to you in order for you to know who should receive a push notification

Alternatively, iOS 7 has a feature that once an app is updated, a blue dot will appear next to the App Display Name. This is built-in and no programming required.